# pip to chose packages from a private index over PyPi even on name conflicts?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, devpi

I have set up a [devpi](https://www.devpi.net/) server to host my own Python modules. I would like to use pip to install them and for pip to *install in preference my modules, not those in PyPi*.

So far, I have this:

```
[global]
timeout = 60
index-url = http://devpi.example.org/root/public/+simple/
trusted-host = devpi.example.org
extra-index-url = http://devpi.example.org/root/pypi/+simple/
```

Which works fine as long as there is no name conflict. If there is, the highest version wins which is not what I want.

I really do not wish to register empty projects on PyPi just to have the names reserved.

*Is there any way to get what I want?*

Comment: You should delegate package resolution to `devpi`: use a single index that inherits from `root/pypi`. `devpi` will then install packages from PyPI if they are not found on local index, acting like a PyPI proxy. However, if the package is provided by your local index, `devpi` will use it regardless of what version is available on PyPI. This is the protection against package spoofing and is turned on by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified my `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` like so:

```
[global]
timeout = 60
trusted-host = devpi.example.org
index-url = http://devpi.example.org/root/public/+simple/
```

and made sure that the `/root/public` inherited from `/root/pypi` like so:

```
devpi use http://devpi.example.org/
devpi use http://devpi.example.org/root/public --set-cfg
devpi login root --password="MyS3kre7Pwd"
devpi index /root/public bases=root/pypi  # ← vital command.
```

Running:

```
devpi list mead --all
```

gives me *what I wanted*:

```
http://devpi.example.org/root/public/+f/d12/59ed3e5cf01ca/mead-0.4.0.dev1.tar.gz
http://devpi.example.org/root/public/+f/046/0f3dee895eb46/mead-0.4.0.dev0.tar.gz
http://devpi.example.org/root/pypi/+f/978/98e728d01b4d3/mead-0.0.11.tar.gz    
http://devpi.example.org/root/pypi/+f/45d/b104905aeabc2/mead-0.0.10.tar.gz    
http://devpi.example.org/root/pypi/+f/da0/c1b3bf979ca6a/mead-0.0.9.tar.gz     
http://devpi.example.org/root/pypi/+f/49c/770889ecd3c7a/mead-0.0.8.tar.gz     
http://devpi.example.org/root/pypi/+f/12d/10190b47367e8/mead-0.0.7.tar.gz     
http://devpi.example.org/root/pypi/+f/34a/6dd6cd6c52c67/mead-0.0.6.tar.gz     
http://devpi.example.org/root/pypi/+f/ba8/0cd76854e2253/mead-0.0.5.tar.gz     
http://devpi.example.org/root/pypi/+f/1d7/6c5dd5229333b/mead-0.0.4.tar.gz     
http://devpi.example.org/root/pypi/+f/47d/208d9cba5ea4e/mead-0.0.3.tar.gz     
http://devpi.example.org/root/pypi/+f/20a/e16978e840e38/mead-0.0.2.tar.gz
```

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I meant with _use a single index that inherits from `root/pypi`_. Now packages not found on `root/public` will be pulled from PyPI and packages on PyPI will be ignored if you have registered a single package version on the local index.

Comment: @hoefling Thank you for your comment and time to read my ramblings.